# Github, add discord webhook by repo organisation id

Tags: javascript, github, discord.js, github-api

I'm looking to add a webhook generated via a discord bot directly to the creation of a repo on a team. Is this possible because I haven't seen an example in the GitHub doc.

Here is my code:

```
const request = await fetch(newUrl, {
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
                'authorization': 'Bearer ' + getStringEnv("GITHUB_TOKEN"),
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name,
                description: description,
                private: true
            })
        })
        console.log(await request.json())
    }catch (e){
        console.log(e)
    }
```

I tried to read the documentation at this URL as well as all that can be said about webhooks:
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads

Comment: What's not working about this code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think I worded it wrong.
I did say that I am looking to add a discord webhook directly to the creation of an organization repo. this is the code where I generate the repo, but I specify later that I do not find on the doc what to put a webhook directly via the api.

Comment: The code you are showing is irrelevant and confusing readers. It has a `catch` without a matching `try`. Also, it's unclear why it matters that you're using a discord bot and that you want to do it after creating the repo. Lastly, if you don't have any code, it's not a good fit for stack overflow. This is the [doc for creating a webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/webhooks?apiVersion=2022-11-28#subscribing). If you try to create one, and it doesn't work, that's a good fit for SO.

Comment: the webhook is already created, I want to add it to github with when I have a return. I don't see how I could do